# Array reference equality in Xcode 6 b3/b4

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I'm just playing around swift with playground.

This code compiled on beta 2 and previous, but not on beta 3 or beta 4:

```
var myArray = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"]

var myArray2 = myArray
myArray2 === myArray

myArray2 += "hello"
myArray2 === myArray
```

It states that *Type [String] does not conform to protocol AnyObject*.

On [Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=3) we read that in b3:

> Array has been completely redesigned to have full value semantics to match the behavior of Dictionary and String. Now a let array is completely immutable, and a var array is completely mutable.

So is it correct to say that we lost reference equality operator `===` for arrays?

Operator `==` is obviously not the same thing, since it compares the array elements.

Comment: `===` is only for `class` (reference-type) and `Array` is `struct` (value-type)

Comment: In beta 2 and previous that's simply not true. Arrays was a mixture, being copied only when modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is fair to say that we lost `===` for arrays. Arrays were made true **value types** which means they are always copied when assigned to a new variable. That makes `===` pointless because it would never return true.

Reference types (or classes) are the only place where `===` makes sense since they are the only types that can have two variables **reference** the same value. That is why the error says that the array does not conform to the protocol AnyObject. `AnyObject` is a protocol for all Classes.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the **Arrays are always copied** part. Now the decision of removing `===` is much more clear to me.